# FreeRtos thread and void* cast

Tags: c++, multithreading, freertos

I'd like to start a thread with the following function :

```
void walkThread(void const *argument)
{
    Gait* gait = const_cast<Gait*>(static_cast<const Gait*>(argument));
    gait->print();
    for(;;)
    {
        osDelay(1000);
    }
}

void Gait::print()
{
    printf("%i\r\n", m_stopped);
}
```

The cast seems to give me a bad address for gait. The print function should print "0" (m_stopped is initialized) but instead it prints a random number.

I start the thread like this, by giving "this" as a parameter.

```
osThreadDef(WalkThread, walkThread, osPriorityNormal, 0, configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE+500);
osThreadCreate(osThread(WalkThread), this);
```

Is there anything wrong here? Should I look somewhere else?

Comment: Are you sure the object is still alive by the time the thread function runs?

Comment: Where and how is the Gait object created  and how did you pass it to xThreadCreate ?

Comment: The Gait instance is saved as a class attribute in an instance created in the main function. I did not check if the Destructor is called but I do not see how this could be possible.
As shown in the previous post, the Gait object is passed in the thread using :

    osThreadCreate(osThread(WalkThread), this);  (Gait is "this")